# php://input returns empty

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js, kohana

I have Backbone application. When model updates PUT request goes to my server.

[image]

Client-side looks good. But on the server side (PHP) I have some trouble. When I first time test this request in PHPStorm:

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

return what I expect. But on the other times it always return empty. I restarted Apache - nothing helps.

I know that

> Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once;

But I thinked that mean one by request. Not once per life :) Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you please post the PHP code that you use to process the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was Kohana problem. In Kohana_Request class there is piece of code, that already opened php://input stream

```
if ($method !== HTTP_Request::GET)
{
    // Ensure the raw body is saved for future use
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `$this->request->body()` to get the request body.