# xmlrpc php record xml to text file

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I am getting xmlrpc xml posted to my server and I want to catch the xml and store it in a text file for later processing.

This is what I have, but I just get a blank text file

```
$getXML = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($getXML);
 $text = $xml->Text;

 $today = date("Y-m-d");

 $randomnr = rand(100000, 999999);
 $datet = date("Ymd-H:i:s");
 $filename = "/var/www/".$datet."-".$randomnr.".txt";


 $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 fwrite($fh, $text);
 fclose($fh);
```

Can anyone see why I cam getting a blank text file?

Comment: fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error. - Which value does it return in your case? What is `var_dump(`$text`);`?

Comment: Are you _sure_ `$xml->Text;` exist? What if you save `$xml->asXML();` instead? (or the raw `$getXML`?)

Answer (score 0):

I found This answer for your question

1)HTTP POST data is usually populated in $_POST, php://input will usually contain PUT data.

2)php://input cannot be opened/read when receiving a multipart/form-data POST, maybe that's what changed client-sided? – Wrikken Mar 28 at 20:01

[file_get_contents('php://input') keeps returning empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937886/file-get-contentsphp-input-keeps-returning-empty)

[php://input returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546660/php-input-returns-empty)

[php://input returning empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463596/php-input-returning-empty-string)